# How to limit COUNT(*) for SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have a query like below. My goal is to count, for each item that itemX is related to through a specific relationship, count how many has the specific relationship with the item.

```
SELECT ?b ?c (COUNT(*) as ?count)
WHERE{
    itemX ?b ?c.
    ?a ?b ?c.
}
GROUP BY ?b ?c
```

This is a hypothetical result

```
?b|?c|?count
rel1|item1|100
instanceof|human|10000000
rel2|item2|1
```

I run this query through the Wikidata (with appropriate modification.) The issue is ?count can be at millions and easily hit the 60 seconds time limit.

Therefore, I wish a compromise. I still wish a count, but for each ?b-?c pair, I will only look for maximum for 10000 ?a. For instance, if ?b is `instance of` and ?c is `human`, there are millions of humans and listing them all before aggregating may result a timeout. Hence, I wish the query will just list only 10000 ?a for `instance of` and `human` and then aggregate it. The result is below is the desired outcome.

```
?b|?c|?count
rel1|item1|100
instanceof|human|10000
rel2|item2|1
```

I tried something like this.

```
SELECT ?b ?c (COUNT(*) as ?count)
WHERE{
    itemX ?b ?c.
    {
        SELECT ?a
        {
            ?a ?b ?c.
        }
        LIMIT 10000
    }
}
GROUP BY ?b ?c
```

However, I get this result instead.

```
?b|?c|?count
rel1|item1|10000
instanceof|human|10000
rel2|item2|10000
```

I wonder where I went wrong.

Comment: The inner ?b ?c are different (unconnected) to the outer "itemX" ones. Try `SELECT ?a ?b ?c`. The inner query is then "grab 10000 triples" - a sort of sample of the data.

Comment: The important thing is, in addition to the other comment, subqueries are evaluated first. So you won't get 10000 instances per type. That's impossible with a single sparql query. Something that might change in sparql 1.2. right now, you have to use multiple queries